# rethinkdb 'or' filter still returning result even filter params is invalid

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I'm trying to retrieve a result where row 'origin' is equal to 'person' or row 'type' is equal to 'human', below is what I've tried

```
r.db('identitydb').table('connections').filter( 
  ( { "origin" : "person" } ) | ( { "type" : "human" } )
);
```

yes it did return but the problem is even if I put an invalid values e.g.

```
r.db('identitydb').table('connections').filter( 
  ( { "origin" : "persss" } ) | ( { "type" : "humaxxxn" } )
);
```

it still returns the result above like it simply not filtering. Below is the return result

> { "created_at":  "January 06, 2019 | 07:32 AM" , "id": 
>   "99f84427-422b-4768-bed8-4d08fc62ff15" , "origin":  "human" , "type": 
>   "person" }

I even tried

```
r.db('identitydb').table('connections').filter( 
  ( r.row["origin"] == "person" ) | ( r.row["type"] == "human" )
);
```

but unfortunately, same result. Any help, ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am confused that you tagged your question with "rethinkdb-javascript" but your queries are for the python driver. The javascript version of your query works fine:

```
r.db("identitydb").table("connections")
   .filter(r.row("origin").eq("person").or(r.row("type").eq("human")))
```

Comment: im using the rethinkdb admin data explorer

Comment: you mean the web interface? that should accept only the javascript syntax.